# Sustantivo para la cualidad de un código de poder ser demostrado que funciona como debe hacerlo

Tags: solicitud-de-término, sustantivos

Acabo de soltar [el siguiente tuit](https://twitter.com/charliealejo/status/1014134342505951233):

> Tipos de programador:
>
> El mesías: nadie entiende su código pero te dice que tengas fe en que su código funciona.
>
> El científico: nadie entiende su código pero sus pruebas demuestran que funciona.
>
> El literato: da tanto gusto leer su código que qué más da que funcione o no.

Estoy intentando explicar que la clasificación expuesta se hace en base a la legibilidad y ¿demostrabilidad? del código que cada uno escribe, pero no sé si *demostrabilidad* es la palabra correcta. Está formada como *[demostrable](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CAjNzMR)* + *[-bilidad](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BotFPGe)*, pero no sé si expresa el sentido completo de "cualidad de poder ser demostrado que funciona como debe hacerlo".

¿Existe una palabra mejor?

Comment: fiabilidad?  (Estoy pensando en *reliability*, no sé si eso está bien.)

Comment: Charlie, te falta darnos una frase con un __________ donde iría la palabra buscada. Eso es importante. // Se podría evitar quizás problemas con lo largo de una palabra como *demostrabilidad* o *comprobabilidad* con un truco: *lo demostrable, lo comprobable*.  Si la frase es "La clasificación se hace a base de la legibilidad y _____", entonces te propongo "La clasificación se hace a base de la legibilidad y la fidelidad." Este término ("fidelity") la aprendí en el entorno de la educación especial. Se habla de que se está implementando el plan ("IEP") *con fidelidad* (o sea, al pie de la letra).

Comment: @aparente001 efectivamente, la frase es la que puse en la pregunta. Interesante opción la de _fidelidad_, puedes plantearla como respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Si la idea es probar o demostrar que algo funcionará tal como se debe, pues tenemos una palabra ya existente en castellano:

> **[probabilidad](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UDu5ucA)**
>   **2.** f. Cualidad de *probable* (‖ que se verificará o sucederá).

También existe otra, pero está registrado en el DLE como jerga de filosofía (como antónimo de *falsabilidad*), por lo que a lo mejor no su uso no está tan extendido, pero como la programación es algo de lógica y por extensión filosofía, podría valer.

> **[verificabilidad](http://dle.rae.es/?id=beCuYoj)**
>   **1.** f. *Fil.* Cualidad de verificable.

La palabra **demonstrabilidad** se usa aunque sin quedar registrado en el DLE (pero sí en otros), pero echando una mirada a sus usos en Google Books, me parece que también aceptable.  A fin de cuentas, creo que hay poca diferencia entre lo que es *probable*, lo que es *verificable* y lo que es *demonstrable* siempre que la idea sea hacer constancia de hace lo que se espera que haga (obviamente, entre sus otros usos se distinguen más).

Comment: No me había parado a pensar en esa palabra con el sentido que comentas. ¿Entiendo entonces que _verificabilidad_ es otra opción?

Comment: @Charlie también podría ser, aunque el DLE lo tiene registrado como palabra propia de la filosofía (probabilidad no tiene anotaciones sobre el uso)

Answer (score 0):

**Fidelidad**

> La clasificación se hace a base de la legibilidad y la fidelidad.

(O "en base a" como dijiste tú.)

Este término ("fidelity") la aprendí en el entorno de la educación especial. Se habla de que si se está implementando el plan (*Individualized Educational Program*, o *IEP*) con fidelidad (o sea, al pie de la letra).

Answer (score 0):

Creo que una palabra ajustada sería

> [eficacia](https://dle.rae.es/eficacia?m=form)
>
> Del lat. efficacia.
>
> 1. f. Capacidad de lograr el efecto que se desea o se espera.

ya que **de un código primariamente necesitamos que funcione**, que satisfaga el primer objetivo para el que fue escrito